# SQL Query to run in SQL Server Agent to Kill a process

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

SQL Query to run in SQL Server Agent to Kill all processes with wait time over 2 minutes and by host name.

I want to run the job every 10 seconds and monitor processes from a select few host names whose wait times are >2 minutes. I put together the following:

```
select 'kill ' 
    + cast(session_id as varchar(20)) 
    + cast(session_id as varchar(20))
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where host_name = 'TS2012' and wait_time = '120000'
```

Tried the following code and it will kill the hosts but cant get the wait time to resolve.

```
select 'kill ' 
    + cast(session_id as varchar(20)) + cast(session_id as varchar(20))
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where host_name = 'TS2012' and wait_time = '120000'
```

Comment: `wait_time = 120000`… or `wait_time > 120000`?

Comment: Wait time is not a column in that view -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: What do you mean with "wait_time"? Do you mean running time or what

Comment: The "wait_time" in the SQL activity monitor.

Comment: @GMB yes it would be greater than. but still getting issue with the recommended code changes below.

Answer (score 0):

wait time is in another view -- join to it to filter on it.  Like this:

```
select 'kill ' 
    + cast(s.session_id as varchar(20))
from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
join sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats w on s.session_id = w.session_id
where s.host_name = 'TS2012' and w.wait_time_ms >= 120000
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_sessions_wait_stats'.

Completion time: 2023-04-27T16:45:51.3872845-04:00

Comment: @Frizosty -- sorry -- the wait stats table does not have the plural -- I changed it.

Comment: same error exits..

Comment: any other recommendations?

Comment: @Frizosty The table quite clearly does have a `wait_time_ms` column https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 What error message are you getting and did you try it manually?

Comment: @Frizosty -- there is no way you can have the same error -- your error says "Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_sessions_wait_stats'. "  But I have changed the name -- to be 'sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats' so you can't get the same error if you made this change-- that object name is not in the code

Comment: perhaps he doesn't have enough rights to see the view, or have some really old sql server

Comment: @siggemannen then I wouldn't expect him to be able to see dm_exec_sessions

Comment: maybe he got rights for one but not the other. only OP can answer that